# Calling a function using Object type reference (holding a different instance)

Tags: java, object, reference, polymorphism

I have a Dog class described as:

```
class Dog {
//data members
void bark() {
   //Bark Algorithm
  }
}
```

Now in another class which has the main method and in the main method, if I do the following:

```
Object dog = new Dog();
dog.bark();
```

Shouldn't it work as the "dog" reference is holding a Dog instance? Why is this not valid?

The language used here is Java.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is very strongly typed. Java compiler performs a method check at compile time, not at runtime. `dog` is declared as `Object`, so compiler checks if `Object` class has a method named `bark()`. It doesn't, so it throws a compiler error. This is how Java is designed.

Note that this is not a limitation of polymorphism per se, but a limitation of the implementation of polymorphism in Java. This exact same code would perfectly compile (and work) in a more dynamically typed language like Groovy, which also runs on the JVM.

Comment: So is this a limitation to Polymorphism?

Comment: It is a limitation of polymorphism **in Java**. It makes sense that `dog` doesn't have a `bark()` method since it is declared as an `Object`. It is  matter of the type design in Java.

Comment: Thanks.. I think the concept is more clear to me now. To justify the **Strongly Typed** nature of Java, this limitation must have been included in its design.

Answer (score 1):

The class Object does not have a method called bark. Therefore, your code would not compile.

However, this does not mean that the compiler decides what method to call purely based on the reference type. Your reference type decides what methods you *CAN* call, while the instance type will decide what you method you *WILL* call. This is the essential mechanism for polymorphism.

For example,

```
class Animal
{
    void makeSound()
    {
        //Generic animal sound algorithm
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    void makeSound() 
    {
       //Bark Algorithm
    }
}
```

Then

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
Animal animal = new Animal();
dog.makeSound(); //calls bark
animal.makeSound(); //generic animal sound
```

Comment: Using an interface might make a better example.

Comment: Well, it would as Animal is generic, but I didn't want to assume knowledge of interfaces.

Comment: @Kariem So only the methods that are available in the superclass can be called using the reference of that class. Although it depends on the instance type that how the method will work out.

Comment: @Kariem Thanks, but I still think this as a limitation to Polymorphism as Object class is the mother of all classes, then why can't we do the same with an Object reference. Can this be considered as an exception to the rule?

Comment: @N.Pamnani I think you're thinking about this backwards. Children inherent the parents and not the other way around. Therefore, children can do all the things their parents can and then more.

Comment: @Kariem I got the point now. Object class is like super generic, just like singularity as we move down the hierarchy, the classes become more specific.

Comment: @N.Pamnani Think of inheritance as a "is-a" relationship. A Dog is an Animal, but an Animal is not necessarily a Dog ;)

Comment: @m0skit0 yeah, "is-a" relationship is the culprit here actually, Animal is-a Object and that made me do the blunder. :P

Comment: @N.Pamnani Animal is an Object but Object is NOT an Animal. Always loook it both ways. In any case, some other less strict languages do allow that kind of calls, check my answer :)

Comment: @m0skit0 I will keep that in mind. To look both ways :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution here. The compiler decides which function to call based on the reference type and not on the instance type that reference holds.

Like in this case, just like the Dog class, many other animals can also can be instantiated and Object references can be used to refer to their objects on the heap, but not all can bark(). Hence the compiler decides that the function call should be based on the reference type, rather than the instance type.

Comment: Your answer is not entirely accurate. However, you should delete this answer and add your comment as an edit to the original question.

Answer (score -2):

If you're sure about type of `dog` you can always do typecasting

```
Object dog = new Dog();
((Dog)dog).bark();
```

Safe version:

```
Object dog = new Dog();
if (dog instanceof Dog) 
    ((Dog)dog).bark();
```

**UPD**

Polymorphism example:

```
interface Animal {
}


interface Barkable extends Animal {
    void bark();
}

class Dog implements Barkable {
    @Override
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("woof-woof");
    }
}

class Cat implements Barkable {
    @Override
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("meow");
    }
}

class SilentCreature implements Animal {
}

....


Animal animal = new Dog();
animal.bark();

animal = new Cat();
animal.bark();

animal = new SilentCreature();  
// new SilentCreature() returns new animal, but not Barkable 
animal.bark(); // as Animal doesn't have method bark() this code won't compile
```

Comment: But wouldn't that be a drawback to Polymorphism?

Comment: If you want multiple animal types to have a bark method you should use an interface with the bark method and typecast to that.

Comment: @BobBrinks are you suggesting that there should be HAS-A relationship between the classes and the bark behavior?

Comment: @ruX I get what you are doing here, you are composing the behavior with the class, thanks ruX. So here a reference of Animal can call bark() and how the results turn out, depends on the type of instance.

Comment: This is wrong. `animal.bark()` will not compile since `Animal` interface doesn't declare any `bark()` method.

Comment: @m0skit0 can you see me comment in source code about that?

Comment: @ruX I mean **all** `animal.bark()` lines won't work. You're only tagging the last one as erroneous.

Comment: @m0skit0 of course they won't, they even won't compile. Ok i'll update answer

Comment: @m0skit0 TS got confused why ```dog``` doesn't have ```bark()``` method in his example. For me it looks like he missed interface there as he expected to run that method. I showed him how he can do that.